# Segmentation fault in numpy matmul

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting a Segmentation fault when performing a matrix multiplication

```
expanded_model = np.matmul(M, model)
```

where M and model have the dimensions

```
print(len(model), M.shape)
```

which gives

```
1200 (2000, 1200)
```

and the matrix and array are defined as

```
model = np.arange(1200, dtype=np.float64)
M = np.ndarray(shape=(2000, 1200), dtype=np.float64)
```

Any idea what could go wrong here?

```
>> *** Process received signal ***
>> Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (11)
>> Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
>> Failing at address: 0x110
>> [ 0] 2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff65e2cf5a _sigtramp + 26
>> [ 1] 3   libpython3.6m.dylib                 0x000000010a548d3d convertitem + 5965
>> [ 2] 4   libBLAS.dylib                       0x00007fff3a7a7a47 cblas_dgemv + 727
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Which version of numpy are you using? May be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to use `np.ndarray()` to create the array. The documentation advises against it:

> Arrays should be constructed using array, zeros or empty (refer to the See Also section below).

It looks like it contains garbage, like `np.empty()`. Perhaps you want a random `M` to start with? Does that help?

```
M = np.random.random((2000, 1200))
```